# Use the limit rule to find Big Oh characterization of for loop

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Find Big Oh characterization in terms of n, the professor says to use the limit rule for big Oh which says 
f(n) = O(g(n)) means f(n) "≤" g(n) => lim n->inf f(n)/g(n) = c where c is 0< c < inf 
**The algorithm is** 
s←0
 
for i←1 to n<sup>2</sup> do
    for j ← 1 to i do 
        s←s+i

I think the answer would be O(n<sup>3</sup>) because we have n<sup>2</sup> for the first loop and n for the nested loop and then you multiply them together because its nested. But Im not sure where the limit rule comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

You would be wrong.  The inside loop does not run $n$ times for each $i$.

It is unclear whether you are looking for $s(n)$ or the number of additions.

Exactly, $s(n) = \dfrac{n^2(n^2+1)(2n^2+1)}{6}$ while the number of additions is $\dfrac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}$, neither of which is $O(n^3)$.

Comment: Im unclear on the difference between s(n) and the number of additions. What is s(n)? Also for the number of additions why is it n^2*(n+1)^2/2 and not n^2*(n^2+1)/2?

Comment: Suppose for example $n=2$ then the outer loop runs through $2^2=4$ values. The first run through the inner loop will add $+1$; the second run will add $+2+2$, the third $+3+3+3$ and the fourth $+4+4+4+4$, which add up to a total for $s$ of $30$ - what I call $s(2)$ - with $10$ additions.  And you will find (I hope) $30= \frac{2^2(2^2+1)(2\times 2^2+1)}{6}$ while $10=\frac{2^2(2+1)^2}{2}$.